# Replacing digits separated with commas using String.replace("","");

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which looks like following:

Turns 13,000,000 years old

Now i want to convert the digits to words in English, I have a function ready for that however I am finding problems to detect the original numbers (13,000,000) in this case, because it is separated by commas.

Currently I am using the following regex to detect a number in a string:

```
stats = stats.replace((".*\\d.*"), (NumberToWords.start(Integer.valueOf(notification_data_greet))));
```

But the above seems not to work, any suggestions?

Comment: `myString.replace(String str)` takes a String as argument, `replaceAll(String Regex)`  takes regex

Comment: How come you're using regex in `replace` method?

Comment: Darn!! I was not aware! Works like a charm now after using replaceAll();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the number using a RegEx wich allows for the commas. The most robust one I can think of right now is

```
\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*
```

Wich matches any unsigned Integer both with correctly placed commas and without commas (and weird combinations thereof like 100,000000)
Then replace all `,` from the match by the empty String and you can parse as usual:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(,?\\d{3})*"); // You can store this as static final
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) { // Go through all matches
    String num = m.group().replace(",", "");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
    // Do stuff with the number n
}
```

---

Working example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String input = "1,300,000,000";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(,?\\d{3})*"); // You can store this as static final
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) { // Go through all matches
            String num = m.group().replace(",", "");
            System.out.println(num);
            int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Gives output

```
1300000000
1300000000
```

Comment: The only problem is that replaceAll(); replaces the whole string I do not want to lose other elements of the string like "Turns -- years old"

Comment: @user2822178 I don't use `replaceAll`. Only the internal String `num` is stripped of commas for parsing. The String `input` remains untouched.

Comment: Gives me an error atInteger.parse (NumberFormatException) change to parseInt

Comment: What is the content of `num` when you get the error? What is the value of `input`?

Comment: input string is: "13,000,000" here is the complete function:

 `public static void strip(){
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,3}(,?\\d{3})*"); 
  String input = "1,300,000,000"; 
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  while (m.find()) {
      String num = m.group().replace(",", "");
      int n = Integer.parse(num);
      
     
      System.out.println(n); 
  }`

Comment: And `System.out.println(num)` gives what?

Comment: Breaks, at line ` int n = Integer.parse(num);` with the following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method parse(String) is undefined for the type Integer

 at CheckRegEx.strip(CheckRegEx.java:28)
 at CheckRegEx.main(CheckRegEx.java:13)

Comment: @user2822178 Yeah, it's `parseInt`, I typed without an IDE to check function names.

Comment: Done! I had done that previously without declaring input and directly passing "1,300,000,000". Did not work at that time. Works with the input variable and Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 2):

Try the below regex to match the comma separted numbers,

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+
```

Make the last part as optional to match also the numbers which aren't separated by commas,

```
\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*
```

Comment: A more robust RegEx would allow for `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*`. This will match any correctly represented unsigned Integer. (Yours fails at `100,000` and any number < 1000)

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?([0-9][0-9][0-9](,)?)*
```

This matches numbers that are seperated by a comma for each 1000. So it will match

```
10,000,000
```

but not

```
10,1,1,1
```

Comment: You do know that `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`?

Comment: I do, but I like [0-9] more, since it works in practically every regex implementation. This way I don't have to worry if my regex works in Java, awk, Python, grep or whatnot.

Comment: That's interesting. Wich implementation has problems with `\d` or is it just a general precaution?

Comment: Just a general precaution. I noticed, that a lot of more complicated regex-terms don't work in quite a lot of regex implementations (e.g. awk doesn't support lookaheads). So if there is an equivalent basic term, that doesn't take much more space I tend to use that. I just looked it up, and as far as I can see, awk doesn't support \d for [0-9]

Comment: Okay so it's fine with Javas' implementation I guess ^^ Do you know of any other problem childs apart from awk?

Comment: Python's and grep's regex handling are a bit different from the Java implementation. A lot of older or rather rudimentary tools have problems with regexes, that extend from the POSIX standard. I don't have any other specific examples though. I work a lot with embedded Linux, where I often don't have anything else than ancient versions of Busybox, so I got used to only using stuff that's in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of `DecimalFormat` instead of a regular expression

```
    DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
    System.out.println(format.parse("10,000,000"));
```